# Using "Union All" with Queries Between Databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, multiple-databases, union-all

I have a interesting situation that I want to see if there is a solution to...I have 4 tables in 4 databases on the same server, all with the same structure:

dbo.IL_Membership in Pnl_IL_2012 database
dbo.NM_Membership in Pnl_NM_2012 database

I want to combine an aggregated dataset from each table into one data set, but I'm trying to make use of the (USE [Pnl_IL_2012] --> Go) Construct to try and grab the data for each aggregate query.

```
select * from 
(USE [Pnl_IL_2012]
GO
select 'IL' as PlanID, sum(Contracts_Hlth) as PROD_Contracts_Hlth from dbo.IL_Membership where [month] between '2012-09-01' and '2012-10-31') Q1
```

union all

```
select * from
(USE [Pnl_NM_2012]
GO
select 'NM' as PlanID, sum(Contracts_Hlth) as PROD_Contracts_Hlth from dbo.NM_Membership where [month] between '2012-09-01' and '2012-10-31') Q2
```

I get these errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Anyone have a way to get union all to work across databases?  I don't need a join just a union...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GO` signals the end of a batch, so this can't be used in the middle of queries.

Instead, reference the tables using the [three part name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
Pnl_IL_2012.dbo.IL_Membership
```

Giving you the following query:

```
select 'IL' as PlanID, sum(Contracts_Hlth) as PROD_Contracts_Hlth 
from Pnl_IL_2012.dbo.IL_Membership 
where [month] between '2012-09-01' and '2012-10-31'

union all

select 'NM' as PlanID, sum(Contracts_Hlth) as PROD_Contracts_Hlth 
from Pnl_NM_2012.dbo.IL_Membership 
where [month] between '2012-09-01' and '2012-10-31'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just used that and it was exactly what I needed.